# Transformer(Multi-Head-Attention) with Audio features, Val accuracy always the same

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transformer-model, attention-model

I have some problems with the creation of a transformer model. Whatever I change in the parameters, I always get 11.86% validation accuracy which is not even changed If I train the model with only 1 input. The accuracy changes only if I change the size of the validation data. I tried to follow [this guide](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/). I have 500 audio and I extracted their 20 MFCC features. So let's say I have a (500, 20, 1) size of data. The labels are the emotions that belongs to these audios. Since I already have the data, I did not use any embedding or tokenizing. Here is the code right now:

```
class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, key_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.1):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=key_dim)
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(key_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

key_dim = 2  # Embedding size for each token
num_heads = 2  # Number of attention heads
ff_dim = 32  # Hidden layer size in feed forward network inside transformer

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(20,1))
transformer_block = TransformerBlock(key_dim, num_heads, ff_dim)
x = transformer_block(inputs)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(7, activation="softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-7,amsgrad=False,name='Adam')
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(
    x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=15, validation_data=(x_val, y_val)
)
```

This starts training but the results are like this:

```
30/30 [==============================] - 1s 17ms/step - loss: 1.9461 - accuracy: 0.1213 - val_loss: 1.9471 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
Epoch 2/15
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 1.9457 - accuracy: 0.1489 - val_loss: 1.9479 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
Epoch 3/15
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 1.9456 - accuracy: 0.1489 - val_loss: 1.9489 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
Epoch 4/15
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 1.9452 - accuracy: 0.1489 - val_loss: 1.9501 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
Epoch 5/15
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 1.9451 - accuracy: 0.1489 - val_loss: 1.9510 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
Epoch 6/15
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 1.9450 - accuracy: 0.1277 - val_loss: 1.9523 - val_accuracy: 0.1186
```

Val accuracy is 11.86% even I change any of the parameters and even I change the size of the train data. I think I made a mistake while creating the model but I could not find the problem. At first I tried normalization and one hot encoding but after I saw that even I use 1 data for the train, it gives 11.86% accuracy, I thought that this problem is completely independent from the data. There should be a problem in the creation of the model but I can not see it.

This is the model summary:

[image: model summary]

Edit 1: I tried increasing the unit of dense layers but the result did not change.

Edit 2: I tried to train a simple CNN model with the same data. I got exactly 11.86% accuracy with it too. So I am not sure what is the problem. Maybe the data has a problem?

Comment: I guess you take the average of mfccs on the time dimension, so why do you use transformers where fully connected networks would do. Also, in the reference example you give, there is a layer for positional encoding which is important in transformers.

Comment: @elbe thank you for the answer, you are right, I got the mean of them. I will try to do it with a fully connected network and also I will try without getting the mean of them.